# RCurl POST request with headers and JSON data

Tags: r, curl, rcurl

So essentially, I'm wanting to get the RCurl equivalent of the following curl call:

```
curl -H "AUTH-KEY: soanclCNdnLDcnlNc" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"documents":["http://localhost:3000/documents/2","http://localhost:3000/documents/4"]}' http://localhost:3000/documents/download?format=zip
```

I was managing to get something from this, but it was always larger than what the curl call produced and wasnt able to be uncompressed:, and can't for the life of me find out what it is.

```
x= list(items=c("http://localhost:3000/documents/2", "http://localhost:3000/documents4"))
headers <- list('AUTH-KEY' = "soanclCNdnLDcnlNc", 'Accept' = 'application/json', 'Content-Type' = 'application/json')
postForm("http://localhost:3000/documents/download?format=zip", .opts=list(postfields=toJSON(x), httpheader=headers))
```

Comment: (1) In your curl call you have "documents" but in your first line of R code you have "items". (2) Did you confirm that `toJSON` is giving you the correct content?

Comment: That as actually just a mistake in me putting it here. It turned out I was handling the content i got back incorrectly. I was using the standard write() R function to write to file instead of writeBin() which produced the correct zip file I wanted. cheers though

Answer (score 3):

While there are  fancier packages nowadays, RCurl still does its honest job.

In general to remap in RCurl:

```
curl -H "AUTH-KEY: xxxx"  \
     -H "Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
     -d '{"key1": "value1","key2": "value2"}' \
     "https://httpbin.org/post"
```

(adjust your headers and fields accordingly)

You use:

```
hdr=c(Authorization="xxxx", `Content-Type`="application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
flds='{"key1": "value1","key2": "value2"}'
postForm("https://httpbin.org/post",
        .opts=list(httpheader=hdr, postfields=flds))
```

Note the backticks for  `Content-Type` to escape the minus.